# Persian DateTimePicker BehComponet.dll Could not install in C# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, persian-calendar

I was using `Visual Studio 2015` and the component `BehComponent.dll` to use `Persian DateTimePicker` and I right clicked on the `ToolBox` and chose `Choose Item` and then I selected this component and It generated the `DateTimePicker Components` in the `ToolBox`.

But after intalling a fresh windows and `Visual Studio 2015`, I did the same thing but I could not install this component.

There was a message that:

> There is no component in BehComponent.dll to be placed on the ToolBox.

Although I could add this component as a reference but the component itself did not appear on the `ToolBox`.

Answer (score 2):

It could easily be solved.

I created a `Windows Form Application` and opened `ToolBox` and simply dragged `BehComponent.dll` on the `ToolBox` then `Persian DateTimePicker` was easily generated itself.